# Regex selecting only first element

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm printing user song from my server like this:

```
<id>0000</id>
<song>Song 1</song>
<id>1111</id>
<song>Song 2</song>
<id>2222</id>
<song>Song 3</song>
```

I'm using regex to get all IDs into array with this pattern `<id>(.*?)<\/id>` but it's only selecting first ID (`<id>0000</id>`). Why it isn't selecting all IDs?

```
NSArray *song_id = [user matchWithRegex:@"<id>(.*?)<\/id>"];
```

Comment: Don't parse XML or HTML with regex. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: Ok, but I want to know why this isn't working

Comment: You probably don't have the multiline and/or global flag set. You'll have to show your code and tell which regex engine (=language) you're using.

Comment: Most likely because you didn't tell it you were using multi-line text.

Comment: How can I tell it I'm using multi-line text?

Comment: `g` is needed for a global match

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sT9mA4/1

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that `g` was needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Multiline` approach with regular expressions:

```
^<id>(.+?)</id>$
```

But mandatory: [use a parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).
See a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hU2rV0/1).